# Puzzle related to sorting a 2-D array in ascending order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

A randomly generated 4x4 2-D array is given to the user, of which one element is definitely 0. Considering 0 to be an empty location, the user will have to exchange the remaining 15 elements with 0 repeatedly until they get the array in ascending order, with 0 as the last element.
At this point, they're allowed to exchange any element with 0.
But how do I modify this code to ensure that are only able to exchange those elements with 0 that are adjacent to it (either above, below or beside it) ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

int check_asc(int a[][4])
{ 
int i, j, previous = a[0][0];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if(i == 3 && j == 3)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == 0)
                return 1;
        }
        else if (a[i][j] < previous)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        previous = a[i][j];
    }
}
return 1;
}

void swap(int a[][4], int &xpos, int &ypos)
{
int arr, temp;

cout << "\n\nEnter number to be swapped with 0: ";
cin >> arr;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == arr)
        {
            temp = a[xpos][ypos];
            a[xpos][ypos] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = temp;
            xpos = i;
            ypos = j;
            return;
        }
    }
}
}

int check_rep(int a[][4], int assign)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (assign == a[i][j])
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}

void main()
{
int a[4][4], assign, xpos = 0, ypos = 0, asc_result, rep_result;

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            a[i][j] = 0;
        else
        {
            do {
                assign = rand() % 50;
                rep_result = check_rep(a, assign);
            } while (rep_result == 0);
            a[i][j] = assign;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nArrange the 4x4 matrix into ascending order. (Consider 0 as a blank space)" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
    }

    do {
        swap(a, xpos, ypos);
        system("cls");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        asc_result = check_asc(a);

    } while (asc_result == 0);

    cout << "\n\tYou win"<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: It resembles the Fifteen Puzzle, just the numbers are not required to be 1..15 (and there may be duplicates).

Comment: Yes here the numbers can be anything till 50, and no duplicates.

Comment: Right, there are no duplicates. BTW, are you aware your `check_rep` function tests for duplicates the whole array, including the part not initialized yet?

Comment: Yes it does check the whole array, and seems to work. What's the alternative ?

Comment: You may check just against those numbers already assigned. First declare `int isduplic( int a[][4], int currenti, int currentj){ for(int i=0; i <= currenti; i++) for(int j=0; j < (i==currenti) ? currentj : 4; j++) if(a[i][j] == a[currenti][currentj]) return 1; return 0;}` then in `main()` initialize the array: `for(int i=0; i<4; i++) for(int j=0; j<4; j++) do { a[i][j] = 1+rand() % 49; } while(isduplic(a,i,j)); a[0][0]=0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just extend your swap function with a piece of code that will check whether the location of the element to be swapped is adjacent to the location of 0:

```
    void swap(int a[][4], int &xpos, int &ypos)
    {
    ...
        if (a[i][j] == arr &&
              ((i == xpos && (j == ypos - 1 || j == ypos + 1)) ||
               (j == ypos && (i == xpos - 1 || i == xpos + 1))))
        {
            temp = a[xpos][ypos];
            a[xpos][ypos] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = temp;
            xpos = i;
            ypos = j;
            return;
        }
```

An improvement would be to separate the check condition and inform the user in case when the element is not adjacent to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Rough Algorithm

1) create a function find location, it will return a structure Point that has x, y integer fields, it will find the x, y location of any piece based on the pieces value, i.e. lets say 0 is entered, if it is located in the top left corner (0,0), a point (0, 0) will be returned

2) create a function that takes in 2 points, the location of the '0' and the location of the piece we wish to swap lets call it S, if S.x = 0.x and 0.y - 1 = S.y or S.y - 0.y + 1 then you know that said piece is directly above or below the 0, now of course you have ot add a few conditions for boundaries so as we dont check outside the grid. Have this function return an int 1 if the piece S is located above/below/beside, 0 if not.

3) if 1 is returned your allowed to do the flip, if 0 is returned find another piece